# Allowing framing on Stack Overflow with Greasemonkey

Tags: discussion, javascript, userscript

I'm using Stack Overflow with Google Reader and the Better GReader plugin for Firefox.

When I try to open a question with the preview function I see the message

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.

Is there a way to prevent this with a Greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 4):

The [framebuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) code of StackOverflow is located at the beginning of the [master.js](https://stackoverflow.com/content/js/master.js?v=4087) file.

There is no way that Grease Monkey could help, but you can configure Firefox, modifying your user.js file, located at your Firefox User Profile folder, adding the following lines:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "noframebuster");
user_pref("capability.policy.noframebuster.sites", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
user_pref("capability.policy.noframebuster.Location.replace", "noAccess");
```

Then restart Firefox.

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users/browse_thread/thread/42a64be1aa31e1d8/76df7564697e076a#76df7564697e076a)

Comment: This does not work for me in FF 3.5.