# Firefox 4 alerts "framing is not allowed" 

Tags: support, firefox

I upgraded to Firefox 4 this morning and noticed for all pages in Stack Overflow I am getting the following pop up. I read this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11709/allowing-framing-on-stackoverflow-with-greasemonkey), but that did not work. I did not get this with Firefox 3.6 though. Any clue on what might be happening?

(The image button in Firefox 4 is also broken when I click on it pastes my clipboard content.)

> `For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.`

[image: Popup: For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.]

Is this something to do with Firefox 4 rendering?

Comment: What OS? I'm running Firefox 4 (Win7 Enterprise) and I'm not seeing any pop up warnings.

Comment: No problems here, Win7 w/ FF4 on SU.

Comment: I am using win XP on this machine. I will try on my ubuntu when I get home.

Comment: No problems on OS X 10.6 either.

Comment: And other browsers at the place you're at don't have the same issue?

Comment: I'm thinking proxy, or adware/virus/worm/trojan.  Can you confirm that all your proxy settings in firefox and the system are turned off?

Comment: Yes it happens without proxy too ...

Comment: Can't reproduce on FireFox 4 on windows 7 64.

Comment: You shouldn't *have* to, but if you haven't restarted your system since upgrading FF, try rebooting now and let us know if you get different results.  Unlikely to change anything, but within the realm of possibility.

Comment: I wonder if it's an ad or something like that which includes an iframe that could be causing it?

Comment: @Spudley, no. [The script](http://stackoverflow.com/content/js/master.js): `if (top != self) {  
  top.location.replace(document.location); 
  alert('For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.');
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's got to be an extension or toolbar that's trying to add a frame around pages.  What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Firebug 1.7.0,AdBlockPlus 1.3.3,GreaseMonkey 0.9,Java Quick Starter 1.0 and JavaScript Debugger 0.9.88.1 .

Comment: I also had all these extentions in 3.5.6 too.

Comment: @CoolBeans, what if you use menu Help, Restart with Add-ons disabled?

Comment: Same thing happens. :-(

Comment: @CoolBeans I'm curious. You have accepted this answer, so obviously it helped you. But can you explain what about it exactly helped you? For future visitors.

Comment: I have no extensions, Firefox 3.5, and also saw this "framing is not allowed" alert.

Comment: @Village Old Firefox versions (6 and earlier) are [explicitly not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208), so it's very likely that this isn't going to be fixed - or worked around, possibly.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this; using the latest current release Firefox 4 and no framing.

I suggest starting Firefox in "safe mode" to disable all extensions.

(It is standard for us to reject framing with the first line of our JavaScript, however.)

Comment: That's what I tried earlier in safe mode but it still happens there. Anyway it must be a one off weird issue. Since nobody else is able to reproduce I would just close this post.

Comment: It does not happen in IE8. I also tired multiple other websites in firefox 4 and only stack exchange sites are giving these errors. Very strange.

Comment: @CoolBeans, you only see that security msg on stackexchange sites because that msg is generated by Stack Exchange's Javascript, not Firefox 4.

Comment: Works great on Chrome!!!

Answer (score 4):

A bit too long for a comment:

- When right-clicking the page to get the context menu, do you get an option "This frame"? (That tells you the browser really thinks it's a frame, and it's not [the JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/content/js/master.js) that is failing.)
- Likewise: what do you get for any other site?
- For the Stack Exchange sites: when disabling JavaScript in Firefox, you will be able to do a "view source" (using Ctrl-U or Command-U) before getting redirected. You might then see some `<frameset>`, and maybe even some comments that explain what inserted that then (which would then NOT originate from Stack Exchange). (Compare with an [example site](http://www.radio-pingvinko.com/) for which you're sure it uses frames; again note that there you will get the option "This frame" in the right-click context menu.)
- Next, after loading without JavaScript and then enabling JavaScript again: does pasting the following in the location bar (address bar) give you anything else but the expected URL?

  ```
  javascript:alert(top.location);
  ```
- If the view source indeed gets you a frame, this might be a good time to get to know [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to see if that was really sent by whatever remote host you're connecting to.
- Today, a `ping stackoverflow.com` should get you IP address 64.34.119.12. (As an aside: `ping6 stackoverflow.com` still fails! [June 8th](http://test-ipv6.com/ipv6day.html) is coming soon...)
- You're not somehow using Google to get to these sites?
- And clicking OK does not get you into an endless loop with the very same message *for that same page* again, right? (The checkbox might indicate otherwise, but maybe that option is shown as you have the same message *for other pages* on Stack Overflow?)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed message Arjan. I dont get it on other sites on only stack exchange profile pages in particular. I will try out the rest of your ideas and let you know.

Comment: The message is generated by the Stack Exchange family website, @CoolBeans. So I would not expect that message on other sites. However, the right-click context menu item "This frame" might also be shown on every other site you visit. If that's true, then something is adding such frame.