# Framing is not allowed

Tags: support

I get an alert just like this one:

[Firefox 4 alerts "framing is not allowed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84462/firefox-4-alerts-framing-is-not-allowed)

However in my case, I receive it on Google Chrome (current version) when uploading a picture.

Answer (score 5):

The plugin *Smooth Gestures* is also causing this error. That does not happen with the plugin *Chrome Gestures*, that offers the same functionality.

Comment: The extension [Clickable links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickable-links/mgamelhnfokapndfdodnmfiningckjia) does also force this error. [Here is a SU test site](http://superuser.com/questions/11099/how-to-download-a-url-as-a-file) where the error occurs if you are using Chrome browser together with clickable links

Answer (score 2):

The

> DivX Plus Web Player HTML5

is causing this error.